# Difference between StaticDataFrame and static DataFrame in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I was reading through the Spark 2.2.0 documentation and found this weird reference to `Static DataFrames` https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#api-using-datasets-and-dataframes

> Since Spark 2.0, DataFrames and Datasets can represent static, bounded data, as well as streaming, unbounded data. Similar to static Datasets/DataFrames, you can use the common entry point SparkSession (Scala/Java/Python/R docs) to create streaming DataFrames/Datasets from streaming sources, and apply the same operations on them as static DataFrames/Datasets.

This is especially confusing because there is a concept of `Datasets` (which I understand as statically-typed dataframes) and `Static DataFrame` and a `Dataset` seems to be overlapping in  my mind now.

What is the difference between `Static DataFrame` and `Regular DataFrame` and `Datasets` in Spark 2.2.0? Is the difference is because of streaming/non-streaming data? Is it because of statically/dynamically typed languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between Static DataFrame and Regular DataFrame and Datasets in Spark 2.2.0? Is the difference is because of streaming/non-streaming data?

Well, let's restructure the quote:

> Since Spark 2.0, DataFrames and Datasets can represent static, bounded data,

In other words data loaded by `read` (`DataFrameReader`):

```
>>> spark.read.text(path).isStreaming
False
```

> as well as streaming, unbounded data.

In other words data loaded with `readStream` (`DataStreamReader`):

```
>>> spark.readStream.text(path).isStreaming
True
```

Static typing doesn't have anything to do with this.

To summarize:

- Spark 1.x:

  - `DataFrame` with static sources.
- Spark 2.x

  - `DataFrame` with static sources a.k.a Spark SQL
  - `DataFrame` with dynamic (streaming) sources a.k.a Structured Streaming.

APIs mostly overlap, so distinctions SQL vs. Strct. Stream. is rather blurry.